# Compile time check for type being index accessible in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have a class of as shown below -

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T> >
class MyClass
{
private:
    Container arr;

public:
    MyClass();
    
    T* get_pointer(size_t index)
    {
         return &(arr[index]);
    }
}
```

How can it be made sure in compile time, that the index can be accessed from the Container type, and the type of that is T.

Comment: It won't compile with `MyClass<int, std::vector<std::string>` nor with `MyClass<int, std::list<int>>`, so you kinda already do check that?

Comment: You can use the C++20 concept to do this.

Comment: What version of C++ can you use?

Comment: Also I would return an T& not a pointer. If your code doesn't have to be the fastest possible consider using at(index) to avoid out of bound acces.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C++17 approach for checking if a container implements an index operator.
Online demo : https://onlinegdb.com/0F-SKnFim

The core is this compile time expression :
`<std::is_same_v<typename type_t::value_type&, decltype(std::declval<type_t>()[0ul])>` where the compiler tries to deduce the type of the index operator on an instance of type_t using [`std::declval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/declval).

```
#include <cassert>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <type_traits>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// C++17 version, use templates and constexpr to deduce if a class implements a method (or operator)
//

namespace traits
{
    namespace details
    {
        // provide 2 overloaded helper functions
        // if the enable_if_t evaluates to true then the
        // overload with int becomes available if not only the overload with double is available

        template<typename type_t>
        static constexpr auto implements_index_helper(int) ->
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<typename type_t::value_type&, decltype(std::declval<type_t>()[0ul])>, bool>
        {
            return true;
        }

        template<typename type_t>
        static constexpr bool implements_index_helper(double)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    template<typename type_t>
    static constexpr bool implements_index()
    {
        // call the helper with an int, if the overload with int is available it will be selected
        // and that returns true otherwise the overload with double (implicit conversion) will be selected
        // and the returns false
        return details::implements_index_helper<type_t>(1);
    }
}

// To enable disable a class based on a compile time condition
// first declare the class template with one extra parameter
template <typename container_t, typename enable_t = void>
class my_class_t;

// then specialize and only allow the specialization 
// if the enable_if_t resolves (which is if the container implements an index operator)
template<typename container_t>
class my_class_t<container_t, std::enable_if_t<traits::implements_index<container_t>()>> final
{
public:
    explicit my_class_t(const std::initializer_list<typename container_t::value_type>& initializer_list) :
        m_container{ initializer_list }
    {
    }
    
    ~my_class_t() = default;

    // I prefer returning references instead of pointers
    // when there is a guarantee a dereferencable address is returned.
    auto& get_reference(const std::size_t index)
    {
        assert(index < m_container.size()); // sanity check for debug builds
        return m_container[index];
    }

    // usually also provide a read only version 
    const auto& get_reference(const std::size_t index) const
    {
        assert(index < m_container.size()); // sanity check for debug builds
        return m_container[index];
    }

private:
    container_t m_container;
};

int main()
{
    // Check that various containers indeed implement index
    static_assert(traits::implements_index<std::vector<int>>());
    static_assert(traits::implements_index<std::array<int,4ul>>());
    static_assert(traits::implements_index<std::string>());

    // and that other containers (or non containers) do not
    static_assert(!traits::implements_index<int>());
    static_assert(!traits::implements_index<std::map<int,int>>());

    // create an instance 
    my_class_t<std::vector<int>> container{ 1,2,3 };

    // get the reference
    auto& value = container.get_reference(0ul);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<int&, decltype(value)>);

    assert(value == 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `~my_class_t() = default;` is harmful, it prevents your class from being moved, unless you explicitly default the move operations (and the copy ones, to not lose them).

Comment: You are right in this case this class can be default moveable/copyable so I should not have added it. (I am used to defining move/copy constructors explicitly when managing resources, I allow move but not copy for example)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do nothing. As long as you don't call `get_pointer`, you won't get any errors even if `Container` doesn't overload `[]`.

The second option is to conditionally disable `get_pointer` using `requires`:

```
T *get_pointer(size_t index)
requires requires{arr[index];};
{
    return &(arr[index]);
}
```

If you have multiple functions that need to be disabled with the same condition, you can extract `requires{...}` to a `concept`.